# LibNoise Perlin.GetValue not returning noise for zero decimal place numbers

Tags: c#, perlin-noise

I'm using the [LibNoise port from C++ to C#](https://github.com/ricardojmendez/LibNoise.Unity) and running into problems generating Perlin noise ([Unity demo here](https://github.com/ricardojmendez/LibNoiseTutorials)). For some odd reason integers never generate any noise. In the code below `_firstValue` on all axis has no decimal places and with `perlin.GetValue(_firstValue);` it returns zero. Adding a decimal place to either x/y/z of `_firstValue` will return a value with `perlin.GetValue`.

If anyone's ever used this library, any ideas on why something so simple like this demo seems to be causing so much of a head ache? Looking through the Perlin class, everything seems OK.

```
Vector3 _firstValue = new Vector3(-31.0f, 83.0f, -7.0f);

Vector3 _displacement = 0.0001f * Vector3.one;

Vector3 _secondValue = new Vector3(14.50f, 20.25f, 75.75f);

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    Debug.Log("Tutorial conversion for http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial2.html");
    var perlin = new Perlin();
    Debug.Log(string.Format("First value: {0}", perlin.GetValue(_firstValue)));
    Debug.Log(string.Format("First value, displaced: {0}", perlin.GetValue(_firstValue + _displacement)));
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Second value: {0}", perlin.GetValue(_secondValue)));
}
```

Comment: When you say that "non-decimal place numbers never generate any noise," are you trying to say that integer value inputs always yields zero?  Or that the function fails?  Or something else altogether?  From what I remember about Perlin noise, zero at integer locations was normal based on the implementation.

Comment: yes that's correct, integer value always returns a zero.

Comment: try perlin .OctaveCount = <some number i.e 5 >

Comment: It is just odd, it always has to have a decimal place and cant be int number.